Ubuntu 22.04 does not boot, problem with boot-repair
I am on a dell laptop for which there is a bios admin pass which I do not possess (the machine was provided to me by my employer, but not the bios admin pass). After the latest update a couple of days ago I rebooted today but the machine goes by default to some sort of "http boot" option (which does not conclude). I have now booted using a live usb and following the instructions on the boor-repair page I have created this
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b8bZ386xBc/ info document.
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme1n1.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

nvme1n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme1n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme1n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on nvme1n1p1

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA107GLM [RTX A2000 8GB Laptop GPU] Alder Lake-HX GT1 [UHD Graphics 770] from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.20.1(1.20) from Dell Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled according to mokutil - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0001,0003,0000,0002,0008,0004,0006
Boot0000  ONBOARD NIC (IPV4)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(ac91a12b203a,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0){auto_created_boot_option}
      dp: 02 01 0c 00 d0 41 03 0a 00 00 00 00 / 01 01 06 00 06 1f / 03 0b 25 00 ac 91 a1 2b 20 3a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 03 0c 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 4e ac 08 81 11 9f 59 4d 85 0e e2 1a 52 2c 59 b2
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,e2663bcf-db12-478e-b5c2-e333f9a9bb1d,0xfa800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
      dp: 04 01 2a 00 02 00 00 00 00 a8 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0f 00 00 00 00 00 cf 3b 66 e2 12 db 8e 47 b5 c2 e3 33 f9 a9 bb 1d 02 02 / 04 04 34 00 5c 00 45 00 46 00 49 00 5c 00 75 00 62 00 75 00 6e 00 74 00 75 00 5c 00 73 00 68 00 69 00 6d 00 78 00 36 00 34 00 2e 00 65 00 66 00 69 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
Boot0002  ONBOARD NIC (IPV6)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(ac91a12b203a,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0){auto_created_boot_option}
      dp: 02 01 0c 00 d0 41 03 0a 00 00 00 00 / 01 01 06 00 06 1f / 03 0b 25 00 ac 91 a1 2b 20 3a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 03 0d 3c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 4e ac 08 81 11 9f 59 4d 85 0e e2 1a 52 2c 59 b2
Boot0003  UEFI HTTPs Boot   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(ac91a12b203a,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)/Uri(){auto_created_boot_option}
      dp: 02 01 0c 00 d0 41 03 0a 00 00 00 00 / 01 01 06 00 06 1f / 03 0b 25 00 ac 91 a1 2b 20 3a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 03 0c 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 03 18 04 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 4e ac 08 81 11 9f 59 4d 85 0e e2 1a 52 2c 59 b2
Boot0004* UEFI HTTPs Boot (MAC:AC91A12B203A)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(ac91a12b203a,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)/Uri(){auto_created_boot_option}
      dp: 02 01 0c 00 d0 41 03 0a 00 00 00 00 / 01 01 06 00 06 1f / 03 0b 25 00 ac 91 a1 2b 20 3a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 03 0c 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 03 18 04 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 4e ac 08 81 11 9f 59 4d 85 0e e2 1a 52 2c 59 b2
Boot0005* UEFI Lexar USB Flash Drive 4BE9E205AF90B8476199   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1fa5ed,0x800,0xee97f8)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi){auto_created_boot_option}
      dp: 02 01 0c 00 d0 41 03 0a 00 00 00 00 / 01 01 06 00 00 14 / 03 05 06 00 0b 00 / 04 01 2a 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 f8 97 ee 00 00 00 00 00 ed a5 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 / 04 04 30 00 5c 00 45 00 46 00 49 00 5c 00 42 00 6f 00 6f 00 74 00 5c 00 42 00 6f 00 6f 00 74 00 58 00 36 00 34 00 2e 00 65 00 66 00 69 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 4e ac 08 81 11 9f 59 4d 85 0e e2 1a 52 2c 59 b2
Boot0006* Linux Firmware Updater    HD(2,GPT,e2663bcf-db12-478e-b5c2-e333f9a9bb1d,0xfa800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi) File(.\fwupdx64.efi)
      dp: 04 01 2a 00 02 00 00 00 00 a8 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0f 00 00 00 00 00 cf 3b 66 e2 12 db 8e 47 b5 c2 e3 33 f9 a9 bb 1d 02 02 / 04 04 34 00 5c 00 45 00 46 00 49 00 5c 00 75 00 62 00 75 00 6e 00 74 00 75 00 5c 00 73 00 68 00 69 00 6d 00 78 00 36 00 34 00 2e 00 65 00 66 00 69 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 5c 00 66 00 77 00 75 00 70 00 64 00 78 00 36 00 34 00 2e 00 65 00 66 00 69 00 00 00
Boot0008* UEFI HTTPs Boot 2 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(ac91a12b203a,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)/Uri(){auto_created_boot_option}
      dp: 02 01 0c 00 d0 41 03 0a 00 00 00 00 / 01 01 06 00 06 1f / 03 0b 25 00 ac 91 a1 2b 20 3a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 03 0c 1b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / 03 18 04 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 4e ac 08 81 11 9f 59 4d 85 0e e2 1a 52 2c 59 b2


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme1n1 : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme1n1p1   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
mapper/luks-e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme1n1p1   : isnotESP, fstab-has-bad-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
mapper/luks-e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme1n1p1   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme1n1
mapper/luks-e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 3E8AA78E-E1B5-452A-BC77-4C5E7ABF0A80
         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1  2048 2000408575 2000406528 953.9G unknown
Disk nvme1n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 341B5215-796E-4585-90D8-785F8867FC10
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme1n1p1       2048 1718749183 1718747136 819.6G Linux filesystem
nvme1n1p2 1718749184 2000406527  281657344 134.3G Linux swap
nvme1n1p3 2000406528 2000408575       2048     1M BIOS boot
Disk sda: 7.46 GiB, 8006926336 bytes, 15638528 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x001fa5ed
     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 15638519 15636472  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk mapper/luks-e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765: 953.85 GiB, 1024191365120 bytes, 2000373760 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:8007MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Lexar USB Flash Drive:;
1:1049kB:8007MB:8006MB:fat32::boot, lba;
mapper/luks-e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765:1024GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (crypt):;
1:0.00B:1024GB:1024GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB:;
1:1049kB:1024GB:1024GB:::;
nvme1n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB:;
1:1049kB:880GB:880GB:ext4::;
2:880GB:1024GB:144GB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
3:1024GB:1024GB:1049kB:::bios_grub;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                                          FSTYPE      UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                                             
└─sda1                                        vfat        068B-308C                            001fa5ed-01                          UBUNTU 24_0 
nvme1n1                                                                                                                                         
├─nvme1n1p1                                   ext4        711ea7d2-cacd-4935-952b-011d08fae3b0 03081bb3-4c0c-4e75-8ac5-1d8c399f0a1e             
├─nvme1n1p2                                   swap        0b27af58-64b9-46fe-ade9-9c8dfe3897c6 ffb59214-ba27-4845-aba7-9fd52a9107c9             
└─nvme1n1p3                                                                                    16191ab1-73e8-4c26-ab73-7d855825a29e             
nvme0n1                                                                                                                                         
└─nvme0n1p1                                   crypto_LUKS e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765 f02d7025-4cb7-4fbb-a43b-0564cc21ec01             
  └─luks-e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765 ext4        8e759d72-984e-4f93-9d23-605535868e2e                                      TheVault    

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                       Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/luks-e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765 763.4G  14% /media/ubuntu/TheVault
/dev/nvme1n1p1                                        462.8G  37% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p1
/dev/sda1                                               1.7G  77% /cdrom
efivarfs                                              135.6K  68% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/luks-e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765 ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme1n1p1                                        ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1                                             vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
luks-e963c225-9f9e-4d1f-af41-b53211e25765

=================== nvme1n1p1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   711ea7d2-cacd-4935-952b-011d08fae3b0
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme1n1p1/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=711ea7d2-cacd-4935-952b-011d08fae3b0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme1n1p2 during installation
UUID=FC03-7EE6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=0b27af58-64b9-46fe-ade9-9c8dfe3897c6 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme1n1p1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme1n1p1: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 190.465873718 = 204.511174656  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 639.803318024 = 686.983581696  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 197.904869080 = 212.498735104  boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-35-generic                  1
 639.803318024 = 686.983581696  boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic                  2
 197.904869080 = 212.498735104  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 349.504589081 = 375.277694976  boot/initrd.img                                1
 282.750972748 = 303.601545216  boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-35-generic               7
 349.504589081 = 375.277694976  boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic               1
 282.750972748 = 303.601545216  boot/initrd.img.old                            7

=================== nvme1n1p1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec  2  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec  2  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec  2  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec  2  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Sep 20  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec  2  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec  2  2022 41_custom

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on nvme0n1p1


================================= User choice ==================================

Is there RAID on this computer? no



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to remove grub-efi) and reinstall the grub2 of
nvme1n1p1 into the MBR of nvme1n1.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no ESP partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a ESP partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag).
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on nvme1n1 (PM9A1 NVMe Samsung 1024GB) disk!

The boot files of [nvme1n1p1 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them.   
You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk).   
This can be performed via tools such as gParted.   
Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot-Repair].   
(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)   
The boot of your PC is in UEFI mode.   
You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.

The immediate problem that I face now is that I am not sure what to answer in this question by boot repair: "The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no ESP partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a ESP partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag). You may want to retry after mounting your encrypted partitions so that the tool can verify their contents. (cryptsetup open)
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?" (No/Yes...)
For info: the encrypted partitions do not contain bootable elements. It is just a backup drive.

If the ESP partition is gone it sounds like your hard drive is bad. I would be returning it to the company IT guys.

This sounds like the safest thing to do. Thanks! Problem is that I will still loose my setup/system.

Shall I make it an answer?
